# How to implement api testing in Angular

Tags: angular, mongodb, express

I'm using mongoose, nodejs, express and Angular. I want to perform forgot password functionality.

I tested my api with postman it works but I don't know how to perform this using Angular. I don't know how to pass the id to the url as we pass id in postman. How can I pass the id of particular user having the email id by the user to forgotpassword form and pass it to reset password form? Please help me to resolve this problem.

Here is my api.js file

```html
router.get('/reset/:id', (req,res) => {
    let userData =req.body
    User.findById(req.params.id, (error,user) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
       } else 
           if (!user) {
               res.status(401).send('Id Does not exists')
           } else {
            user.save( { $set: user.password = userData.password})   
            res.status(200).send(user)
           // User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, {$set: {password: userData.password}})
           }
       })

})
```

```html
<!-- this is my component.ts file-->
  onRestPswrd() {
    console.log(this.resetPswrdForm.value)
    this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/reset",  this.resetPswrdForm.value)
    .subscribe(
      res =>{
         console.log(res);
         this.login= true;
         this.resetPswrd = false;
        },
      err => console.log(err)     
    )
  }
}
```

```html
router.post('/forgotPswrd', (req, res) => {
    let userData =req.body
    User.findOne({email: userData.email}, (error,user) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
       } else 
           if (!user) {
               res.status(401).send('Email Does not exists')
           } else {
            // user.save( { $set: user.password = userData.password})   
            res.status(200).send(user)
           // User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, {$set: {password: userData.password}})
           }
       })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I understand from your question:

- you have a login form with `user_id` and `password`
- If you press PassWord forgot the id is send to your backend
- You need to know how you can get your ID from angular front end

And this is my answer:

```
//in your component.ts

onRestPswrd() {
    console.log(this.resetPswrdForm.value)

    // I added this
    const user_id = this.resetPswrdForm.value.user_id
    this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/reset/" + user_id,  this.resetPswrdForm.value) 
    .subscribe(
      res =>{
         console.log(res);
         this.login= true;
         this.resetPswrd = false;
        },
      err => console.log(err)     
    )
  }
```

I also added a "/" behind your reset in the http-link and I also suggest you  to look into "How to use Services with angular"